# Quasar2 Vue3 Cypress Webpack Compilation Error

Tags: webpack, cypress, vuejs3, quasar-framework

`test/cypress/integration/pages/MyPage.cy.js`:

```
import MyPage from '../../../../src/pages/MyPage.vue';
```

Running E2E test bumps into the following error:

```
Webpack Compilation Error
./src/pages/MyPage.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|   <q-page padding>
|     <q-input
 @ ./test/cypress/integration/pages/MyPage.cy.js 9:40-86
```

Only happens to E2E tests but NOT component tests. What do I miss? Thanks.
https://github.com/khteh/quasar

Comment: vue-loader, perhaps? https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#vue-cli

Comment: I added the file `webpack.config.js` at the ROOT of the source tree but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `MyPage.cy.js` in the repo, but all of your tests under `test/cypress/integration/pages` are component tests (because they use `mount()`), so you can't run those with Cypress e2e.

The spec `test/cypress/integration/home.cy.js` will run, it is an e2e test.

Because you have `cy.visit('/')` in this test, you will need a `baseUrl` in config.

First start the app with `yarn quasar dev`, it will tell you what port is being used (probably 8080). Make that your baseUrl in config.

Final thing missing from config is `supportFile`.

It's needed because you have `<project root>/test/cypress/support/index.js` not conventional `<project root>/cypress/support/e2e.js`.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  component: {
    ...
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    specPattern: 'test/cypress/integration/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    supportFile: 'test/cypress/support/index.js',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have similar file content. Added `webpack.config.js` at the ROOT of my source tree but to no avail.

Comment: I think I need to see the folder structure.

Comment: https://github.com/khteh/quasar

Comment: Thanks, I started working with it but no luck yet. Will try a clean start, may take a bit of time.

Comment: I removed the `mount()` and use `cy.visit()` in the `beforeEach()`. However, it fails to reach the page. :(

Comment: Which test is it?

Comment: `/fibonacci` and `/autogenerate`

Comment: It works if I use `/#/fibonacci` and `/#/autogenerate`